# How can I declare a default constructed char?

Tags: rust

This seems to be a simple question but I am very new to Rust so I am still asking. So, I could not get a way to declare `char` in default constructed or leave uninitialized and this is what I did:

```
let mut r: char = 0 as char;
// let mut r: char; // error
```

I do not know it is right the way to do it or is there are proper way to do it?

Comment: You can just skip specifying the type, e.g. `let mut r; r = '*';` works just fine. The compiler will understand that the type is `char`

Comment: yes, but still I have to initialized it, right? is there a way to default initialize it like C++?

Comment: Also, see MaybeUninit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply declaring the variable will leave it uninitialized, but the compiler won't let you use the variable until it has been initialized so its only useful in certain contexts.

There is also no shorthand for default constructing a value. There is the [`Default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html) trait that `char` [implements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#impl-Default) (defaults to `'\0'`) so you can choose to initialize it like so:

```
let r = char::default();
```

But depending on what the surrounding code is doing, it may be more succinct to simply set the value explicitly:

```
let r = '\0'; // or 'a' or '0' or whatever you like
```

Comment: Ok, so why I should avoid using first way depending on the surrounding code?

Comment: @foragerDev I'm not saying you shouldn't use the first way. I was simply mentioning the alternative as a matter of style. If you had code that was counting digits in a string (as an arbitrary example), then perhaps '0' might be a better default than '\0', but if there's no material difference then its up to you whatever you think is more clear or convenient.